# CRM 2013 Organization Imported from CRM 2011. Can't start Asynch Services. Error 1069

Tags: asynchronous, dynamics-crm-2013

After backing up 2011 Organization database, restoring on CRM 2013 server, and importing with Deployment manager and an enabled status. I receive Error 503 when trying to access the application.  The Asynchronous Services are not running. When I try to start them, I receive the following error message:

Windows could not start the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service service on Local Computer.

Error 1069: The service did not start due to logon failure.

1) Event viewer shows: Host DEVCRM13STACB: A Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service operation of type 56 has failed...
2) Started CRM App Pool
3) Performed an IIS Reset
4) Filtered views displaying data on query.

Thanks in advance. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The key to resolving this is in this error, "Error 1069: The service did not start due to logon failure." You should do the following to resolve this:

1. Run Services.msc and look at the Log On As account for the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service.
2. Double Click on the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Asynchronous Processing Service and click on the Log On tab.  Either change the service account or re-enter the password.  Typically you can get the logon failure error if the password has recently changed or expired for the service account.